# Toast not working in Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-toast, visual-studio-2019

I have a simple Xamarin Form app with a .net standard project and Android Project. I am facing a problem since the very first day of development is that , I am unable to pull Toast and Activity Indicator on my forms. I dont know why? I tried almost all major plugins as well.

Here's my login code where I want to see a toast. I have used UserDialogs, Forms.Plugin etc and now using Plugin.Toast.

```
  protected void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            try
            {
                CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastMessage("Message"); // Plugin.Toast package
                var userName = TxtUserName.Text.Trim();
                var password = TxtPassword.Text.Trim();
                userController.DoLogin(userName, password);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Mobile # and Password, both are required.", "JCAA", "OK");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert(ex.Message, "JCAA", "OK");
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }


        }
```

### UPDATE

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="JCAA.Views.Login" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Image Source="logo.png" Aspect="AspectFit"  HeightRequest="150" Scale="0.8" ></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="70">
            <Label Text="JCAA" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"    FontSize="50" VerticalOptions="Start"  FontFamily="{StaticResource JostBold}" TextColor="SeaGreen"></Label>
            <Label Text="Jh Cul Art Association" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"     FontSize="10" VerticalOptions="Start"  FontFamily="{StaticResource JostBold}" TextColor="SeaGreen"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout   HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="140" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="30">
            <Entry x:Name="TxtUserName" MaxLength="10" Placeholder="Mobile Number" FontFamily="{StaticResource JostReg}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Keyboard="Numeric" Completed="TxtUserName_Completed"></Entry>
            <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="Login" Clicked="BtnLogin_Clicked"  BackgroundColor="DarkSlateBlue" TextColor="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource JostReg}" FontSize="20"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label Text="New User?? Register your mobile with us." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="DarkSlateBlue" FontFamily="{StaticResource JostReg}"></Label>
                <ImageButton Source="signup.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="40" Aspect="AspectFit"  x:Name="BtnSignUp" Clicked="BtnSignUp_Clicked" ></ImageButton>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Lost Phone!!"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="9" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="DarkSlateBlue" FontFamily="{StaticResource JostReg}"></Label>
                <ImageButton  x:Name="BtnRecoverPassword" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="40"  Aspect="AspectFit"   Clicked="BtnRecoverPassword_Clicked" Source="passwordreset.png" ></ImageButton>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout  Padding="30" HeightRequest="220"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label  FontSize="13" TextColor="DarkSlateBlue"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span FontFamily="{StaticResource JostThin}"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="18">
                            powered by
                        </Span>
                        <Span Text=" a" TextColor="Red" ></Span>
                        <Span Text="r" TextColor="Black"></Span>
                        <Span Text=" technosoft" TextColor="Black">
                        </Span>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Above is the xaml of my login page. I am using conventional windows form style of development. No MVVM is involved here.
This toast is in my login page & my toast is coming up when all codes written the BtnLogin_Clicked event executes and the next landing page shows up. Since my login process taks 4-5secs, so in that window , i want to show toast to the user.

this is happening in my entire application. Only display alert is poping up as desired.

Now, I have changed my code to use native toast, via these two ways:

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("Toast Message"));
   DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("Toast Message");
```

But none of the above is working as expected. toast is coming up but after executions of all blocks of code.
[image]

VS2019 and all modules updated.

Comment: Hi , what's the version of xamarin forms used in project ? And you can share the full code of `ContentPage` , I will check that .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Please check. Update the content page xaml and added additional content. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing , however not finding the reason . Whether the version of xamrain forms is the latest version ? Not the version of VS .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, If its latest VS then its obvious its should have the latest package. Anyways, Just updated my VS to 16.5.5and Xam Form version is 4.6.0.726+446-sha.d0dc59903-azdo.3681414, earlier it was 4.5.0.725

Comment: Okey ,  I have tride in my local site with a new created project , it works . So , if you can share a sample new created project link with reproduced this prolem here , I will check it in my local site :-)